# Deploying Activiti workflow to OSGI(Felix)

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, activiti

I have developed a activiti workflow, I am trying to call the workflow through the code from an OSGI bundle but it gives the dependency errors.
What would be the correct way to deploy the workflow into OSGI container?

Comment: What did you try and what errors did you have?

Comment: A pretty general question. I can say that packaging Activiti into a Felix OSGi container works well. We (BP3) have successfully done it for a couple of clients. However I would need a lot more detail from you before I could provide any hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [feature for apache karaf](https://forums.activiti.org/content/deploy-activiti-osgi-bundles).